# Consuming Server Sent Events in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-functions, signalr, servicestack

I am working on a service which consumes SSE from the Validic Inform platform to handle wearable device data, and process it for our other various services. Currently there is a complex solution in order to handle this data, and I want to try and simplify it.

I have looked at SignalR, but it seems to not actually support consumption of other sources, even if its through SSE protocol which is supported. It is dependent on being able to call a hub, which we do not have. We want to directly talk to Inform.

I have also looked at ServiceStack...but it seems they want to charge you for what ought to be a simple library.

Are there any better ways to consume SSE within a ASP.NET API / Azure functions without rolling your own code with a HttpClient?

Comment: FYI there's no cost for using ServiceStack's [Server Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/server-events) client and implementing a reliable async networking events client with heartbeats and auto retries isn't exactly simple. Either way the SSE client is only suitable for consuming ServiceStack Server Events which relies on heartbeats to implement its reliable connection that other SSE endpoints don't have.

Comment: @mythz Yes, I have looked at that client. I did not see (or understand) if it is only going to be functional with other ServiceStack implementations, but you give the impression that it may be proprietary in that sense like SignalR. Per their licenses, for my use case it wouldn't be free regardless. [Their licensing and pricing states we are not within the free parameters.](https://servicestack.net/pricing)

Comment: the library is not restricted by the [Free Usage Quotas](https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas) so there’s no technical limitations on using it without a commercial license.